# Fortran namespace conflicts

Tags: namespaces, fortran, fortran-common-block

I'm working on coupling a couple of simulation codes together.  Currently, there are 3 codes but there may be more in the future.  You can think of information exchange in the following diagram:

```
 sim1  <====>  sim_main <=====> sim2
```

The information exchange is done via a limited interface on each side.

I recently diagnosed a problem where a common block in sim1 had the same name as a subroutine in sim2 which was causing a segmentation fault.  The easy solution is to change the name of the common block in sim1, however that's not ideal because if the developers of sim1 come out with sim1-2.0, then I'll have to dig in and change the name of that common block again.  Since the interface is relatively limited, I'm wondering if a better solution would be to write a simple module:

```
module sim2_mod
contains
include "sim2.f90"
end
```

As this should put all the routines in sim2 into the sim2_mod namespace which could be `use`d on a limited basis.  Is this a good idea?  a bad idea?  Are there situations where this wouldn't work?  Do common blocks used in sim2 still have global scope?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, if `sim2.f90` only contains lines which, when spliced into your proposed `sim2_mod`, form a syntactically valid Fortran source file, your suggestion will work.  If not you'll have to edit the source.

While you're doing that you might as well make it a module anyway and use-associate it in `sim_main`.  Once you've got that far, you can add an `only` clause, with some renaming, on the `use` statement and work round the name clash that way.

Common blocks do indeed have global scope throughout your program, I think the consensus within the Fortran-writing community is that the preferred way to avoid the issues that this global availability can cause, not only the issue that you currently face, is to replace them with a module which defines all the variables that the common block contains.  You can then use the module variables with a bit more control over the availability and naming of the (formerly) global variables.

This approach can be tiresome to implement and does raise the possibility that the next release of `sim1` will need to be reworked too.  But then, isn't it about time you told the developers of `sim1` to drop the common blocks and implement something a little more modern ?

Comment: Thanks -- Although I don't think I'll be convincing any of the devs to modernize their code.  I think it would be easier to learn an obscure language like Chef, translate `sim1` into Chef and then couple that ... :-p